# All my java projects are giving errors after installing new JRE in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I installed an older version of JRE all my projects start to give compiler errors . (There is a cross and (Unbound) message onBuild Path for project) When I checked, they still see the uninstalled JRE in path. I did some of them and changed one by one but isn't there a quick way to add new JRE to all my current projects at one time?
I have almost 80 projects and to make them one by one is time consuming.

Thanks

Comment: Import them again from your version control system.

Comment: How can I achieve this can you explain a bit more? I have all the class files in workspace. Where to import?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your projects are likely referring to their JRE using its name in the preferences.  Go into your Installed JRE preference page and just make sure the new correct JRE that's actually there has the same "name" as the old one that's been uninstalled.  In the future, set your projects' JREs using the Execution Environment (Edit that entry from the Libraries tab).
[image: Java Build Path Property page for the project]
[image]

To fix all of your projects quickly, open the project .classpath files for a fixed project and the broken one, and use the Search menu to kick off a massive find/replace through all of your .classpath files.

Comment: nitind Thanks so much. Finding JavaSE-1.7 with JavaSE-1.6 in all project files and "build project" worked.!!! Thanks again!!!! I love Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 2):

Right click on any projects->properties->java Build path->

```
      1)mark the JRE version in order and support 

      2)Add JRE system library in libraries.
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be done through correct usage of the IDE. Your projects would have to be setup to use the workspace runtime, in which case setting a new default runtime in the workspace would swap it out in all projects. But you may have to run an 'update project configuration' first, I'm not sure about that.

The alternative is to do what I do and that is to use Maven; then you control everything from your poms and not the Eclipse configuration, plus the settings even still apply when not using Eclipse. Its darned useful to be able to build binaries without having to boot up your IDE first, or integrate it all with little effort into a build server / continuous integration environment.

Answer (score 0):

May be this page should solve your problem.

[Help Eclipse Platform](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-assign_default_jre.htm)

Comment: I did this but this affected only current project.